# QWebView doesn't load any external resources if it loads a html-file from qresources

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qwebview, qwebkit

As described in the title my problem is that qwebview doesn't load a html file correctly if it resides in my resources. It loads it perfectly if I load it from outside of the resources as normal local file. But this is not an option for me. I would like to bundle the file with the application.

EDIT: By the way, I'm talkin' about external resources from the web. (e.g. http://host.org/somejavascript.js)
Thanks for any help

Comment: Are resources referenced in the html file local or remote?

Comment: Sorry. I'm talking about web-resources

Comment: How do you load a file from resources into QWebView?

Comment: @Piotr Dobrogost: I load it via the load() method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please take a look at the second parameter of
`void QWebView::setHtml ( const QString & html, const QUrl & baseUrl = QUrl() )`
According to [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwebview.html#setHtml):

> External objects such as stylesheets
>   or images referenced in the HTML
>   document are located relative to
>   baseUrl.

Below is code that works for me.

```
#include <QtCore/QFile>
#include <QtCore/QUrl>
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
#include <QtWebKit/QWebView>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow window;
    QWebView webview(&window);

    QFile source(":/google.com.html");
    source.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    webview.setHtml(QString::fromUtf8(source.readAll().constData()), QUrl("http://google.com"));
    window.setCentralWidget(&webview);
    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: This is not exactly my Problem. I'm using load() by the way. But my problem is that I have a in my html file a script tag: <script src="http://external.org/script.js"></script>. Using that in local file context works perfectly but loaded from resources it simply isn't fetched and executed. I really can't understand that. Thanks for your help

Comment: @domachine Right, my solution is only for **relative** resources if you don't want to put them in resource system.

Answer (score 2):

External URLs must have a schema to make them external, otherwise "external.org/script.js" looks for "script.js" under the "external.org/" sub-path, "http://external.org/script.js" is an absolute URL.

Edit:
Say you have this HTML file as the resource ":/file.html" and it is coppied from "http://example.com/":

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>My HTML</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/code.js"></scipt>
 </head>
 <body>
  <img href="/image.jpg" />
 </body>
</html>
```

Then to display this correctly you would need to do the following:

```
QFile res(":/file.html");
res.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly|QIODevice::Text);
my_webview.setHtml(res.readAll(), QUrl("http://example.com/");
```

That way, WebKit knows where to fetch "code.js" and "image.jpg" from. Using `QWebView::load()` will not work, as the root URL will be some internal URL, the one starting with qrc://, and WebKit will look for "code.js" and "image.jpg" in your applications resources. Basically, you can only use `load()` when all the relative URLs in the document come from the same place as the URL is pointing to. And if you used `load(QUrl("qrc:///file.html"));` in the case above, the URL (`qrc:///file.html`) is pointing to your resource system.

If you want to also include your resources in the HTML, you can use the qrc:// URLs in the HTML file.

Comment: Sorry again. All my urls have a scheme :-) My mistake