# QWebView doesn't load external javascript (google charts)

Tags: javascript, html, qt, webview, qwebview

What im trying to do is to generate "custom" maps depending on what the user wants. For that Im using [GeoCharts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart) which basicly is to include 2 javascript in the html and another one for the selected information.

So I created QWebView to render that HTML (wich will be autogenerated on each request)  like the one below:

```
 GeoXML::GeoXML(QWidget *parent) :
        QMainWindow(parent),
        ui(new Ui::GeoXML)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);


        QWebSettings::globalSettings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptEnabled, true);
        QString excRoute = QDir::currentPath ();


        QFile file(excRoute+"/index.html");
        if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
            QMessageBox::information(0, "error", file.errorString());
        }
        QString html= "";
        QTextStream in(&file);
        html = in.readAll();
        file.close();


        ui->webView->setHtml(html, QUrl("file:///"+excRoute+"/"));

    }
```

the HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='res/loader.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="res/jsapi.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="res/index.css"/>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
     google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['geochart']});
     google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMarkersMap);

      function drawMarkersMap() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Country', 'Poblacion'],
        ['Costa Rica', 'Norte de Costa Rica'],
        ['Mexico', 'Sur de Mexico'],
        ['Nicaragua', 'Nicaragua']
      ]);

      var options = {
        sizeAxis: { minValue: 0, maxValue: 100 },
        region: '013', // Western Europe
        displayMode: 'regions',
        colorAxis: {colors: ['#e7711c', '#4374e0']} // orange to blue
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    };

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It does render my page. I see the red background color I put in the css but I'm unable to see the map. If I open the html in chrome it does work but not in qt's QWebView.

I Included both js files in the qrc aswell, put them as external files (hosted in goolges website) and localy (like the snippet below) but it didn't work, also went thought [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34184704/qwebview-not-loading-external-javascript) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126294/qwebview-doesnt-load-any-external-resources-if-it-loads-a-html-file-from-qresou) posts with no luck.

Also, the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebview.html#setHtml) reads:

> When using this method, WebKit assumes that external resources such as
>   JavaScript programs or style sheets are encoded in UTF-8 unless
>   otherwise specified. For example, the encoding of an external script
>   can be specified through the charset attribute of the HTML script tag.
>   Alternatively, the encoding can also be specified by the web server.

which leads me to think that it should render my map by default.